# Python sum() function with list parameter

Tags: python, list, int, sum, typeerror

I am required to use the `sum()` function in order to sum the values in a list. Please note that this is DISTINCT from using a `for` loop to add the numbers manually. I thought it would be something simple like the following, but I receive `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`.

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
numsum = (sum(numbers))
print(numsum)
```

I looked at a few other solutions that involved setting the start parameter, defining a map, or including `for` syntax within `sum()`, but I haven't had any luck with these variations, and can't figure out what's going on. Could someone provide me with the simplest possible example of `sum()` that will sum a list, and provide an explanation for why it is done the way it is?

Comment: Hmm. You tried those 3 lines in the interpreter and it didn't work?

Comment: Yes. This is using Python 3.3.2 if that helps...

Comment: I'd used sum somewhere else. Thanks for that - I didn't expect the variable to whinge about having the same name as a function. :)

Comment: One of the truly great things about Python is that functions are first-class objects -- they can be passed around just like variables. Thus, there would be no way for it not to "whinge." This also means that you technically could have renamed the `sum` function to something else. But please, don't do this.

Comment: I should also mention that the assignment to numsum was only to step through the code. It was originally coded as print(sum(numbers)) hence the extra parentheses for the numsum assignment.

Comment: One more thing, just because I think it's funny: `nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]` ... `sum = sum(nums)` (works) ... `sum = sum(nums)` (broken!)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Have you used the variable `sum` anywhere else? That would explain it.

```
>>> sum = 1
>>> numbers = [1, 2, 3]
>>> numsum = (sum(numbers))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

The name `sum` doesn't point to the function anymore now, it points to an integer.

Solution: Don't call your variable `sum`, call it `total` or something similar.

Comment: Just about to post this. I think this is the only thing it could be.

Comment: you can also mention that he should avoid using reserved words or built-in function names in any case

Comment: Laziness on my part, as I expected this to be 10 seconds of coding. *puts hands on the Bible* I'll never take shortcuts in coding again :)

Answer (score 2):

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
numsum = sum(list(numbers))
print(numsum)
```

This would work, if your are trying to Sum up a list.

Answer (score 2):

In the last answer, you don't need to make a list from numbers; it is already a list:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
numsum = sum(numbers)
print(numsum)
```